# Error "Settings to access printer 'printername' are not valid" when printing from Windows service

Tags: .net, printing, windows-services, network-printers

I get the error mentioned when printing to a network printer.

The error does not occur when run under XP/Win2003, in a WinForm app or when a local printer is used.

The error does only occur when run as a Windows Service under Vista/Win7/Win2008 and printing to a network printer.

The Windows service runs under a network user that has access to the network printer. Before I print I check if the printername (including network path) is ok by looping through the available printers.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that stumbles across this issue in the future.

Double check that your **Printer Name** is correct as it could also be the reason you might be getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding the printer to the SYSTEM user via a registry hack as described in the Microsoft doc: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184291/en-us.

Answer (score 0):

In my case we got same error for windows 10 os client computers.
I think the error is related users and their permissions.

After making the client computers to our company's domain the error was fixed.